# Can't plot in R from tmux

Tags: r, tmux

I'm able to `plot()` in `R` from a regular terminal, but I can't do so from a `tmux` pseudo-tty. `png()` works fine but I can't write to the monitor.

**UPDATE:** Sorry, there's no error message. `R` merely fails to "print" to the monitor.

**UPDATE 2:** <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> `:showenv` returns

```
DISPLAY=:0                                                                     
SSH_AGENT_PID=1786
-SSH_ASKPASS
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-ebteUtjL1719/agent.1719
-SSH_CONNECTION
WINDOWID=18928777
XAUTHORITY=/home/me/.Xauthority
```

Comment: Having the same issue on mac osx. My `$DISPLAY` shows the same values in and outside tmux and I can start `xterm` fine too. R version 3.0.1.

Comment: @nikola I somehow got this to work sometime in the past two years, although I'm not sure what I did. I'll post an answer if I remember—but know that it _is_ possible.

Comment: thanks, I'd appreciate if you post how you got it to work, but I realise it's been a while since you asked first :). Thanks anyhow, I'll also write up an answer here if I get anywhere on my own.

Comment: @nikola Same here. Sorry this Q is not so helpful as it could/should be.

Comment: Did you try `ssh -X boxWhereYouRunTmux` ?  Works for me, see documentation for the `-X` option to `ssh` ...

Comment: @nikola Had the problem again, this old Q came up when I searched, and I was able to fix it this time. Don't know if you are still looking for an answer.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel It was just on my laptop. `tmux` keeps my ptty sessions even if GNU terminal decides to shut all of the "interfaces" down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### fix in R

```
Sys.getenv('DISPLAY')
Sys.setenv("DISPLAY"=":0.0")
X11()
qplot(...)
.Devices
device.list()
```

should do it.

---

#### fix in tmux

You can also type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, `:setenv DISPLAY :0.0` to change it from `tmux` rather than from `R`.

---

### Why does this happen?

It might have to do with where you open the tmux (virtual terminal versus GNOME terminal) when you initially run the command `tmux` to initiate the session manager.

It's good to `echo $DISPLAY` in the terminal and `Sys.getenv("DISPLAY")` in R. See stuff like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31283/error-in-r-unable-to-open-connection-to-x11

You can also run `capabilities()` in R and if `capabilities()$X11 == FALSE` then that's what to work on fixing.

I messed around for a while and then was able to do `X11(); qplot( my.ggplot )`. Check `?X11` for a little more information too.

Comment: If I am going to fix in R where should I type this, please.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you included the error message, but it sounds like your `DISPLAY` environment variable isn't set properly inside `tmux`. Issue `echo $DISPLAY` from outside your `tmux` session, and make sure `DISPLAY` is set to the same thing inside `tmux`.

You can use the `update-environment` command in `tmux` to configure `tmux` so that it automatically updates particular `tmux` environment variables with their values from the external environment. See the [tmux manpage](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1) for details, or search the web for "tmux update-environment" for various other pages that describe this feature.

Comment: Sorry, there is no error message in `R`. It just doesn't print to the screen.

Comment: `echo $DISPLAY` within `tmux` and in regular `lxterm` both return `:0`.

Comment: Also:  can you do things like `xclock` or `xterm` before you start `tmux`?  And after?